# css: horizontal list positioning issue only with 2 or more li elements

Tags: css, list

I'm trying to create a horizontal list, something like this

```
<nav class="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li class="active">
            <a>Bar Foo</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>Foo Bar</a>        
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The problem is that with only 1 li element it works (like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9qR3h/4/) ) but with 2 the first li item is not positioned correctly (like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9qR3h/3) )

Can someone explain to me whats happening?

UPDATE: remove type with class 'active' on anchor!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use absolute positioning. Just do as following:

```
li.active a {
    color: #abc522;
    padding: 20px 40px 13px;
    width: 146px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9qR3h/5/)

Comment: thnx. Do you also have an explanation why (in my case) the li elements  effected each other using positioning 'absolute' ?

Comment: one issue I noticed with your answer is that when the label gets shorter/longer the layout breaks.

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri `position:absolute;` will start rendering from it's parent left top position. So in that case also it would be work. And it shows smaller width because I gave smaller padding. You can replace `40px` with higher value to get more width.

Comment: I understand. And in the case with 1 li element all that makes sense. But when I add a second li, it doesn't position the first at the top,left of the ul element. What I need is a tab with a fixed width which can hold different content. Is that possible with your solution?

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri If you add second li then it consider present of first li because first li is also with absolute positioning. You can use without fixed width. Use just padding. No need to give width.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the class active from the first list item tag.

```
<nav class="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li> <-- Here
            <a class="active">Bar Foo</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="active">Foo Bar</a>        
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

OR

```
<nav class="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li class="active">
            <a>Bar Foo</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
            <a>Foo Bar</a>        
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Or alternatively...add it to the second ;)

Comment: Or that if you want it to have the css properties. Thanks @ExtPro

Comment: sorry for the typo, I've updated my question. The active should only be on the li element